# Android google maps shown in phone but doesn't shown in tablet

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I created an activity, I shows the google map. I do all these step in the link below.

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/

When I try it on Samsung Galaxy Note 2, I get this screenshot:

[image]

But when I try it on Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1, I get this(No map shown, only zoom buttons):

[image]

Here is my `Manifest.xml`:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.android.app"
     android:versionCode="1"
     android:versionName="1.0" >
<permission
    android:name="com.example.googlev2map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.googlev2map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- Required to show current location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.android.app.SplashScreenLoading"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.android.app.Map"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_map" >
    </activity>

    <!-- Goolge Maps API Key -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyAvlLrKpq0Pf-6xzzHqtq-XattJ_zf58pk" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

And this is my `Map.java` code:

```
   package com.android.tuyap;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Map extends FragmentActivity {
    // Google Map
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        double latitude = 41.020133;
        double longitude = 28.542910;

        // create marker
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Marker title");

        // adding marker
        googleMap.addMarker(marker);
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude, longitude),15));
    }

    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            SupportMapFragment fm = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
            googleMap=fm.getMap();
            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.map, menu);
        return true;
    }
    }
```

And xml:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/splash_screen_background"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/main_menu_gradient_header"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/backButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/back_button" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtSubHeader"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="Text Header"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/SubHeaderTextSize" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/mainMenuButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/main_menu_button" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/headerLayout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Why I can't show the map on the Galaxy Note 10.1 tablet?

Comment: Try to uninstall the app and install it again, it may be happens when you have changed in the manifest file and directly test on the device with out uninstalling the previous installed app. And also try to clean your project this time.

Comment: Yes! Problem solved after uninstalling and reinstalling procedure. Thanks a lot!

Comment: you can either remove your question from the stack over flow or simply accept my answer so that future user can be understood the reason or the answer.

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled several times and also used various clean install tablet emulator and in no case the map was displayed on any tablet. is there any other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Try to uninstall the app and install it again,` it may be happens when you have changed in the manifest file and directly test on the device with out uninstalling the previous installed app. And also try to clean your project this time. It will be only happens when your manifest file or any xml file will not be reflected Either you forget to clean the project or uninstall your previous project, device is not the case for working or not working the google map.

Comment: I just installed it completely new on a new tablet emulator and it still doesn't show the map on the tablet. When I test the very same app on a phone emulator I can see the map. I also tried to uninstall and re-install the app several times on various tablet emulators. Didn't help...

Comment: @e-nature It looks like API key issue. Please double check. You also need to make sure that you need to run your app from the same computer through which you registered your SHA1 key on google play console. So, it also happens when it doesn't match.

Comment: I think I figured out why it's not working. With the emulator I can't install Google Play which seems to be required for the Maps API to work. Trying to find an actual physical Android tablet now so I can test it in a real life situation.

Comment: @e-nature Kindly check you have installed google play service package for Android version whichever is used in your emulator and google play service updates in Extra package.